# Null object reference error using pictures in /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I have a function to send pictures from the Uri (camera or gallery).
This is working taking a picture with the camera and using some images from the gallery, for example with the logs:

- `debug: img path : file:///storage/emulated/0/fname_1494169335416.jpg`
- `debug: img path : /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/OpenCamera/IMG_20170507_162430.jpg`

But it's not working with the path `/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/...` like this :

- `debug: img path : /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/fname_1493561293693.jpeg`

I have this error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
```

This is my `postFile()` function :

```
public static void postFile(Context context, String url, String fileUri, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        if (myCookieStore == null)
        {
            myCookieStore = new PersistentCookieStore(context);
            client.setCookieStore(myCookieStore);
        }
        client.setSSLSocketFactory(MySSLSocketFactory.getFixedSocketFactory());

        File myFile = new File(Uri.parse(fileUri).getPath());

        Log.d("debug", "img path : " + fileUri);

        File compressedImageFile = new Compressor.Builder(context)
                .setMaxWidth(1920)
                .setMaxHeight(1200)
                .setQuality(35)
                .setCompressFormat(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG)
                .setDestinationDirectoryPath(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath())
                .build()
                .compressToFile(myFile);

        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        try {
            params.put("profile_picture", compressedImageFile);
        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.d("error", "error catch");
        }
        Log.d("absolute url", "" + "*" + getAbsoluteUrl(url) + "*");
        client.post(context, getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }
```

Comment: You did not post code where Bitmap.getWidth() is used. Anyhow that bitmap was null. Dont use bitmap pointers that are null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :
It's because I don't delete my file after compress, so when I want to compress a file compressed before, it crash.
So i put a `file.delete()`